# Replacing text in string using values from an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string in this format

```
$update_script = "update public.textcontrols3 set textboxvalue='@textboxvalue',textcontrols_id='@textcontrols_id',textcontrols3_id='@textcontrols3_id' where textcontrols3_id='@textcontrols3_id' ";
```

Now I want to replace all the placeholders thus the text with the `@` in from with values from an array such as `$reverse['1','abc','medo'];`

I tried using this approach:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($reverse);$++) {
  $copy_reverse = 
    preg_replace("/(@".$field_name.")/",$reverse[$i],$update_script);
}
```

Where `$field_name` is a variable coming from the database which is equivalent to the text comes after the `@` symbol. Thus the output I want to achieve is:

```
update public.textcontrols3 set 
textboxvalue='medo',textcontrols_id='abc',textcontrols3_id='1' where 
textcontrols3_id='1'
```

Comment: So you mean the above solution does not work for you?

Comment: `<=sizeof($reverse)` should be `<sizeof($reverse)`, otherwise you'll access outside the array. But it would be even simpler to use `foreach()`.

Comment: You have different `@fieldname` placeholders in the string. `$field_name` doesn't change in the loop, so every iteration replaces the same placeholder.

Comment: And since that placeholder will be replaced during the first iteration, the other iterations won't do anything.

Comment: Why are you updating `textcontrols3_id` with the same value it already has?

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the $update_script variable again and again. So it will replace the last field and revert to the original one. So took a copy of $update_script to $copy_reverse and keep replacing them.

```
$reverse= ['1','abc','medo'];
$copy_reverse = $update_script;
for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($reverse);$i++) { 

   $copy_reverse = preg_replace("/(@".$field_name.")/",$reverse[$i],$copy_reverse); 

}

echo $copy_reverse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can your parameter array contain the field names?  If so give this a try:

```
$update_script = "update public.textcontrols3 set textboxvalue='@textboxvalue',textcontrols_id='@textcontrols_id',textcontrols3_id='@textcontrols3_id' where textcontrols3_id='@textcontrols3_id' ";

$params = [
  "textboxvalue" => "1", 
  "textcontrols_id" => "abc",
  "textcontrols3_id" => "def"
];

foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
  $update_script = 
    preg_replace("/(@".$key.")/", $value, $update_script);
}
```

[runnable sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ce9b0546298eb79f128acbf0f77c58fff38a5bc)

Comment: Thanks guys after combining all the suggestions you gave me i have finally got it   working .@james, i replace $copy_reverse variable with the $update_script variable which got it  working. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what you have as far as the field names and values, but assuming that you have an array of fieldnames and the values you show above.

The first thing is to just add an `@` to the start of the key, then combine the keys and values using `array_combine()`.

Then use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace the field values.  `strtr()` works better when replacing a sequence of strings as the order in which your fields are can affect the result, `strtr()` always does the longest keys first to ensure this is done correctly.

```
$update_script = "update public.textcontrols3 set textboxvalue='@textboxvalue',textcontrols_id='@textcontrols_id',textcontrols3_id='@textcontrols_id1' where textcontrols3_id='@textcontrols_id1' ";

$fields = [
    "textboxvalue",
    "textcontrols_id",
    "textcontrols_id1"
];
$params = [
    "1",
    "abc",
    "def"
];

array_walk($fields, function (&$keyName) { $keyName = "@".$keyName;} );
$update_script = strtr($update_script, array_combine($fields, $params));

echo $update_script;
```

Another thing I would like to raise is that if you are trying to create your own 'prepared' statements, you should instead use either PDO or mysqli prepared statements as they provide other features which are invaluable for modern web sites.

Answer (score 0):

`PDO` is better and more safely way do execute your query.

Example:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass, $options);

$sql = "UPDATE public.textcontrols3 SET
    textboxvalue=':textboxvalue',
    textcontrols_id=':textcontrols_id',
    textcontrols3_id=':textcontrols3_id'
    WHERE textcontrols3_id=':textcontrols3_id' ";

$data = [
  "textboxvalue" => "1", 
  "textcontrols_id" => "abc",
  "textcontrols3_id" => "def"
];

$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Substitution and escaping implementing just via one string `$pdo->prepare($sql);`.

You can read more about `PDO` at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo